# add buttons in front of javacameraview Android

Tags: android, camera, javacameraview

I have a javacameraview in my main activity. I would like to put some control buttons in front of the camera

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gustavo.tassio.opencvnativeandroid.Principal">

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:show_fps="true"
    app:camera_id="any"
    android:id="@+id/cameraOpenCv"/>
```

```
JavaCameraView cameraView;
    cameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.cameraOpenCv);
    cameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    cameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
```

it is like this now, just the pure image, my idea is to put the buttons on this scene

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YKyP.jpg

Comment: What do you mean in front? Can you post an image to see how it looks now?

Comment: Some Buttons in front of the camera, and this is my scene now https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YKyP.jpg

Comment: Could you add an image of how you would like for it to look with the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add buttons to your framelayout, they will be displayed as you wish. The views in framelayout are displayed in chronological order. When you change visibility of a subview of a framelayout, it's order does not change, all subviews that you added after it either in xll or programmatically will be drawn "above".

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for my project